# Airflow SSHOperator Command Timed Out when executing Python script

Tags: python, ssh, airflow

I created a DAG that successfully uses SSHOperator to execute a simple Python script from a server(note I have set `cmd_timeout = None`

When I change the simple Python script to a more complex script, I get an error for  "SSH command timed out"

Additionally, if i log into the server, open CMD and execute `C:/ProgramData/Python/Scripts/activate.bat && python C:/Users/Main/Desktop/Python/Python_Script.py`, which is the one that "times out". It is successful, so I don't believe it is an issue with script or access.

Is there an additional setting that must changed to avoid the SSH command time out when executing commands?

Log:

```
[2023-03-09, 21:31:53 UTC] {ssh.py:123} INFO - Creating ssh_client
[2023-03-09, 21:31:53 UTC] {ssh.py:101} INFO - ssh_hook is not provided or invalid. Trying ssh_conn_id to create SSHHook.
[2023-03-09, 21:31:53 UTC] {base.py:73} INFO - Using connection ID 'server' for task execution.
   [2023-03-09, 21:31:53 UTC] {transport.py:1874} INFO - Connected (version 2.0, client OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1)
[2023-03-09, 21:31:53 UTC] {transport.py:1874} INFO - Authentication (password) successful!
[2023-03-09, 21:31:53 UTC] {ssh.py:465} INFO - Running command: call C:/ProgramData/Python/Scripts/activate.bat && python C:/Users/Main/Desktop/Python/Python_Script.py
[2023-03-09, 21:32:03 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1772} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py", line 158, in execute
    result = self.run_ssh_client_command(ssh_client, self.command)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/operators/ssh.py", line 143, in run_ssh_client_command
    exit_status, agg_stdout, agg_stderr = self.ssh_hook.exec_ssh_client_command(
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/hooks/ssh.py", line 526, in exec_ssh_client_command
    raise AirflowException("SSH command timed out")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: SSH command timed out
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this.  I had to change cmd_timeout = None to cmd_timeout = 7200.  You could choose a different arbitrary large number.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the error message correctly, the exact place it is throwing the error message is from SSHHook instead SSHOperator

```
File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/providers/ssh/hooks/ssh.py", line 526, in exec_ssh_client_command
raise AirflowException("SSH command timed out")
```

So, the solution is easy, should set the `cmd_timeout=None` in SSHHook. E.g.

```
ssh_hook = SSHHook(ssh_conn_id="you_ssh_conn", cmd_timeout=None)
```

I tried with SSHOperator, hitting the same error, until I set the `cmd_timeout=None` in SSHHook instead SSHOperator.